# Nested convergence of random variables: a.s. and in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

A sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges pointwise to a weighted sum of two other sequences of random variables $Y_n$ and $Z_n$.

$~~~\lim_{n\to\infty} |X_n - (a Y_n + b Z_n)|=0$

In addition, $Y_n$ and $Z_n$ converge in distribution to **independent** normal distributions.

$~~~Y_n\stackrel{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, $~~~~~~~~~Z_n\stackrel{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

as $n\to\infty$. Is it true that

$~~~X_n\stackrel{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0,a^2+b^2)$

And if yes, what would be the shortest argument? It seems to me that Slutsky's theorem
or the continuous mapping theorem can not be directly applied.

Comment: The equation $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = aY_n + bZ_n$ has ambiguous notation. The left-hand side does not depend on $n$ while the right-hand side does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $Y_n=Z_n=N\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and let $Y$ and $Z$ be independent standard normal random variables. Then $Y_n\xrightarrow{d}Y$, $Z_n\xrightarrow{d}Z$, and $Y+Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,a^2+b^2)$. However,
$$
X_n=(a+b)N\xrightarrow{d}\mathcal{N}(0, (a+b)^2).
$$

---

The result holds, however, when $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge jointly to $\mathcal{N}(0,I_2)$.

Comment: I edited the first limit. I hope this doesn't change the question for you (otherwise I'll post a new question). Why is it true if $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge jointly?

Comment: @lts_me That's because the convergence in distribution of a sequence of random vectors $\{W_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ to $W$ is equivalent to the convergence of $\{t^{\top}W_n\}$ to $t^{\top}W$ for every $t\in\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: But is convergence in distribution transitive, so that $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} a Y_n +b Z_n$ and $a Y_n +b Z_n \stackrel{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0, a^2+b^2)$ implies $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to}\mathcal{N}(0, a^2+b^2)$?

Comment: That's true. If $V_n-W_n\xrightarrow{d}0$ and $V_n\xrightarrow{d}V$, then $W_n\xrightarrow{d}V$ as well (by the uniqueness of limits).